# undefined _other_node in nil:NilClass error in Neo4j with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, neo4j

I am using Neo4j 2.0.1 with rails 3.2.1. I am getting an error which seems very basic, and yet I can't seem to solve it. I'd appreciate any help with it!

Here's my code snippet:

```
rels1 = identity1.rels(:outgoing,:friends)
if !rels1.nil? and rels1.count > 0
  friendships12 = rels1.to_other(identity2)
end
```

where identity1 and identity2 are objects of a subclass of Neo4j::Rails::Model.

The error I get is on the line "friendships12 = ...." and it says

```
"undefined method `_other_node' for nil:NilClass"
```

What am I doing wrong? Initially I tried the obvious:

```
friendships12 = identity1.rels(:outgoing,:friends).to_other(identity2)
```

This was based on the rails guide for neo4j (http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/guides/basic.html, see "Finding Relationships between two nodes"). But that gave me the same error, which is why I tried it as above. But the error persists.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error and I didn't know the cause. I got around it by using select and looking for the end node.

```
identity1.rels(:outgoing, :friends).select{|r| r.end_node == identity2}.first
```

Also, make sure you're saving the node after creating the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing 'puts rels1' ?

If there is a one-to-many relationship between identities and relations [which I guess there is], doing identity1.rels will return an array. 
You can check if that's happening by doing 'puts rels1', if rels1 is an array, then you need to do rels1.first to get the relationship object and then do to_other on it.

EDIT: I went through http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/guides/basic.html and noticed this:

```
node1.rels # => an *Enumerable* of all incoming and outgoing relationship of any type
```

What this means is that you need to do something like

```
identity1.rels(:outgoing,:friends).to_other(identity2) do |x|
# Your code that works with relation object x, here
end
```

Essentially, you're iterating through each of the relation objects.

Read this [http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/enumerables/] for more information.